# Strange behavior when updating timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, mariadb

There is MariaDB-10.3.18 table as:

```
create table switching_log
(
    item_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    switched_off timestamp,
    switched_on timestamp
);

select * from switching_log;
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| item_name | switched_off        | switched_on         |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 201197010 | 2019-10-01 08:36:08 | 2019-10-01 08:35:49 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

When i update 'switched_off' then 'switched_on' is not changed

```
UPDATE switching_log set switched_off = now()   where item_name = '201197010';

select * from switching_log;
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| item_name | switched_off        | switched_on         |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 201197010 | 2019-10-01 08:40:28 | 2019-10-01 08:35:49 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But when i update 'switched_on' then 'switched_off' updated too.

```
UPDATE switching_log set switched_on = now()   where item_name = '201197010';

select * from switching_log;
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| item_name | switched_off        | switched_on         |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 201197010 | 2019-10-01 08:40:40 | 2019-10-01 08:40:40 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Salman A , MariaDB-10.3.18

Comment: @harp1814 Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE switching_log`. Most likely, you have setup the following attribute on `switched_off` column: `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya, great! You are right , Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This behavior is by design](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/#automatic-values):

> MariaDB has special behavior for the first column that uses the
> `TIMESTAMP` data type in a specific table when the system variable
> [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) is not set (which is the default
> until MariaDB 10.10). For the first column that uses the `TIMESTAMP`
> data type in a specific table, MariaDB automatically assigns the
> following properties to the column:
>
> - `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
> - `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
>
> This means that if the column is not explicitly assigned a value in an
> `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query, then MariaDB will automatically initialize
> the column's value with the current date and time.

To solve the problem, disable "automatic values" feature for the timestamp column using the workarounds described in the article. The simplest and predictable approach would be:

```
create table switching_log
(
    item_name varchar(20) not null,
    switched_off timestamp null,
    switched_on timestamp null
);
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ET84734)

Comment: I tried  "switched_off timestamp DEFAULT NULL"  but get "ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'switched_off'
" . So "switched_off timestamp DEFAULT "'0000-00-00 00:00:00'" is okay

Comment: Turns out that timestamp columns are `NOT NULL` if NULL/NOT NULL is not specified. So besides the zero-date, the other option is to make the column nullable (see fiddle).

Comment: According to the mariaDB doc,  you can also disable automatic update by specifying a `DEFAULT` clause without `ON UPDATE` clause for the timestamp column on creating table.